# Magento 1.9 set custom field/attribute when order is set to complete

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-status

When order change status from "x" to "complete" I need save when order was completed. I am trying to achieve this with sales_order_save_commit_after event. Problem is that I can't save order when the change is made. Order is completed when Invoice and Shipment were submitted in admin for particular order. I made custom attribute on order completed_at when date and time need to be store.

config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <mycompany_mymodul>
                    <class>MyCompany_MyModul_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>orderUpdate</method>
                </mycompany_mymodul>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_commit_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Observer.php

```
public function orderUpdate($observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    if ($order->getOrigData("status") !== "complete" && $order->getData("status") === "complete") {
        $order->setCompletedAt(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()));
        Mage::log(print_r($order->getData(), true));
        //$order->save();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Try to move your code to `sales_order_save_before` and change your condition to `if ($order->getData("status") === "complete" && $order->getCompletedAt() == null) ` or whatever the `completed_at` default value is. That way you avoid the problems with saving in the after event and should have the correct date saved only once.